# Trying to display a ASCII string but it is truncated

Tags: c++, hex

I'm trying to display hex characters as ASCII but it is being truncated after \x00. I understand that \x00 means NULL, but is there a way to somehow 'skip' this value and have all of the hex values displayed?

```
int main () 
{
    const char* blob = "\x31\x00\x32";
    std::cout <<"hexChar=" << blob  << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:
`hexChar=1`

I want the output to also include the last character which is 2 (0x32):
`hexChar=1 2`

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you always want to print exactly three characters? If not, how do you want the number of characters printed to be determined? (Why not use `std::string`?)

Comment: Hello! Not gonna be always 3 characters. Now I tried to use std::string but still can't have the character after \x00 display :(

Comment: Is it possible to take a custom representation of hex in your blob? say something like "hx31hx00hx32" ?

Comment: @Kay So how do you want to determine how many characters to output?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that NUL-terminated string (which is what everyone understands a bare `const char *` without an explicit lengh as) is terminated by a NUL.  So your string only has one character, and only one is printed -- the `'\x32'` character, while in memory, is not part of the string.  By definition, such a string cannot contain a `'\x00'` character as it terminates the string.

You would need to use some other representation that can contain a NUL, such as a `std::string`:

```
int main () 
{
    std::string blob("\x31\x00\x32", 3);
    std::cout <<"hexChar=" << blob  << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to this it is finally working! (sorry for the late thank you!)